# How do I do so that people can register on my wordpress site?

Tags: php, login, user-registration

I've been given a task by my teacher to do a "social network" for a game. To begin with, I want to make a custom theme where people at first have the opportunity to register and login. As I have understood, it should already be such a function, or do I have to fix it myself if I make my own theme? You do not need to give me an direct answer but do you have tutorials or something that shows how to do everything I want to do? I have really good knowledge in html and css and some of php.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable user registration in `Settings->General` and checking the box for `Anyone can register`. You then can provide your users links to `/wp-register.php` and `/wp-login.php`.

If you are looking to build a social network I would look into the BuddyPress plugin: https://buddypress.org/

Comment: Thank you for your well-described quick response! Do you happen to know a tutorial on how to create a custom wordpress theme for registration, login, and so on? I did not quite understand what you meant by "You then can Provide your users links to /wp-register.php and /wp-login.php.".

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you really need, the usual way of activating user registration in the settings and giving your users a link to http://www.yoursite.com/wp-register.php (for registering) and http://www.yoursite.com/wp-login.php (for logging in after registration) might be all you need, as described by Josh Mountain. If you want a fully fledged community, mentioned BuddyPress might be best for you.

However, if you only want to give users a front-end option to register and login, the plugin [Pie Register](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pie-register/) might help you best, including customisable forms with extra fields (which you can use elsewhere on the site with a bit of research). You wouldn't need any programming knowledge for getting along.

(However, you would probably need a user permission editor then which varies depending on what you actually need your user registrations for. You can do that via user role definitions or even content specific for single users, mostly with a further plugin.)